# How to perform a full text search on all stored procedure definitions

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, full-text-search

Good day, I am specifically trying to perform a search through my storedprocedures with the aim of finding a procedure that does not contain a cetain word. Example "nolock".

I understand and i successfully achieved this with a query like below.

```
   Select Name as [Procedurees with no nolock] from 
database.sys.procedure WHERE (OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) 
NOT LIKE '%myKeyword%' .
```

The above successfully returned the names of procedures without the keyword in them. However, the stored procedures script are mostly long and may require the use of the keyword more than one time in a single procedure. Example may be after each "FROM TABLE name" i need a key word "with nolock" . I want the search to be perform till the end of the procedure and where exist a "TABLE NAME", a "mykeyword" must follow else return the procedure name among those with no "mykeyword".

Since i have like twelve table names i want to use, i thought i could use CASE like

```
     Select Name as [Procedurees with no nolock] from database.sys.procedure
 WHERE (OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) NOT LIKE '%Mytable NAME , then plus the keyword%'.
```

This does not look ok for me because i have quite few tables names and it also possible that the table name may appear numerous time in the procedure and may be have the 'keyword' for the first time only. Please is there anyway i can achieve this ? Also sorry for my inability to explain clearly. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your question doesn't really make any sense to me.  But I'll try to answer.

> Blockquote
>   because i have quite few tables names and it also possible that the table name may appear numerous time in the procedure

Can't you just use a GROUP BY to restrict the results to one set per table?

```
Select Name as [Procedurees with no nolock] from database.sys.procedure
WHERE (OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) NOT LIKE '%Mytable NAME , then plus the keyword%'
GROUP BY database.sys.procedure
```

If you want to do this for each table in your database, you can use this:

```
DECLARE @keyword NVARCHAR(20) = 'words'
sp_MSForEachTable  'Select Name as [Procedurees with no nolock] from database.sys.procedure
WHERE (OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) NOT LIKE ? AND  , (OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID)  LIKE ''' + @KeyWord + '''
GROUP BY database.sys.procedure'
```

The ? is replaced by the table name in the stored procedure.

Comment: my concern is whether query i am using above search the whole script or just exit the script as soon as the keyword is encountered?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you turn it around...?

Find the procedures that DO match, and then exclude them ?

```
select name from sys.procedures
where name not in (select name from sys.procedures WHERE (OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%blah%'))
```

Comment: Thanks, thats another way and it works. But my question is, Does this searches the whole procedure text, or exit when the keyword is encountered? e.g lets say there are three "with" in the procedure, how can this be use to identify the whole three instead of returning the procedure name as soon as the first "with" is encountered?